# Getting Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized - AccessDeniedException Error on CreateParticipantConnection

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-connect, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to test the Amazon Connect Chat API in POSTMAN,

1. The first part `StartChatContact` tested/executed and i have got the `ParticipantToken`back in response with `ContactId & ParticipantId` by using `PUT: https://connect.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/contact/chat`
2. But i am unable to run the `POST: https://connect.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/participant/connection`. here is the Request Syntax AWS has given:

**POST /participant/connection HTTP/1.1**

```
X-Amz-Bearer: ParticipantToken
Content-type: application/json

{
   "ConnectParticipant": boolean,
   "Type": [ "string" ]
}
```

i have tried the `ParticipantToken` as header parameter with name mentioned in documentation `(X-Amz-Bearer: ParticipantToken)` as well as used in `Authorization` as Type `API Key & AWS Signature`.
But can't get rid of this error. In response Headers i got `x-amzn-ErrorType: AccessDeniedException` and in body

```
{
        "message": "Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized"
    }
```

How to remove this error? any solution please.

Comment: valid values for "type" parameter is web socket or connection credentials, try using connection credentials as mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_CreateParticipantConnection.html#API_CreateParticipantConnection_RequestSyntax

Comment: still getting the same error message. its so weird to see that i am using everything correctly but it throwing the error. i think there is something wrong with `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this article, which help resolve/fix the problem.

[Getting Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized - AccessDeniedException Error on CreateParticipantConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71216601/getting-unable-to-determine-service-operation-name-to-be-authorized-accessdeni)

I was using Postman and had not set the URL to include "**participant**" after the https as per below for any of the Amazon Connect Participant Service APIs :

https://**participant**.connect.{your-region}.amazonaws.com/participant/connection

Note that the sub-domain is different for the Amazon Connect API vs the Amazon Connect Participant Service APIs.

See the tables on this page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/connect_region.html